# Top 5 values from std::map

Tags: c++

I have a function already that takes out the key value with the most mapped value.

```
// Function for finding the occurances of colors or in this case hex values
void findOccurrances(double * mostNumTimes, map<string, int>  &hexmap, string * colorlist)
{
    map<string,int>::iterator it = hexmap.begin();

    for( ;it != hexmap.end(); it ++)
    {   
        if(*mostNumTimes <= it->second)
        {
                *mostNumTimes = it->second;
                *colorlist = it->first;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there an easy way to expand it to show the top five results?
I know you can copy it to a vector and what not but I'm wanting an easier way of doing it.

Comment: Is this for a class? Did the lecturer not introduce heaps yet?

Comment: No, this is a personal project. And I do not know what heaps are.

Answer (score 4):

Copying into a vector isn't that difficult:

```
typedef std::pair<string, int> Pair;
std::vector<Pair> contents(hexmap.begin(), hexmap.end());
```

Done.

But to find the top 5, believe it or not `<algorithm>` has a function template that does exactly what you want. In C++11, which usefully has lambdas:

```
std::vector<Pair> results(5);
std::partial_sort_copy(
    hexmap.begin(), hexmap.end(), 
    results.begin(), results.end(), 
    [](const Pair &lhs, const Pair &rhs) { return lhs.second > rhs.second; }
);
```

`results` now contains the top 5 entries in descending order.

Answer (score 0):

I'd interchange the key and value and create new map

```
std::map<int,std::string> dst;

std::transform(hexmap.begin(), hexmap.end(), 
               std::inserter(dst, dst.begin()), 
               [](const std::pair<std::string,int> &p ) 
               { 
                 return std::pair<int,std::string>(p.second, p.first); 
               }
               );
```

And now print top five values of `dst` in usual way,

```
typedef std::map<int, std::string> Mymap;
Mymap::iterator st = dst.begin(), it;
size_t count = 5;
for(it = st; ( it != dst.end() ) &&  ( --count ); ++it)
  std::cout << it->second << it->first <<std::endl ;
```

**Edit**:

Use a `std::multimap` if there are same `int` (value) for more than one `std::string` (key) in your `hexmap`

Comment: You probably want a `multimap`, in case the `int` values of `hexmap` aren't distinct.

Comment: @P0W I have some errors when trying to run your code. In the last for loop it gives me an error on the st+5 part.

Comment: @POW Hmm I still get the same error with the updated code. Does the original hexmap also has to be defined as a multimap?

The last for loop still says that it = st matches no operator and that it != st.end() that it has no member called end.

Comment: @POW yeah I changed that but it's still giving me the same errors :/

Comment: @POW Everything works now with your code I just have a problem with how I add values to the map.

I can't find how to fix how you insert values as I do in the following code.
http://pastebin.com/sNn7EvAX

Comment: @user2520739 You should probably start a new post, because parts of code are missing, and I don't wanna populate this comment section, ending up soon in a chat room, which I don't like ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have a little bit confused about the arguments. why you write the function in this way, And I try for this.

```
string colorlist;
double max_val = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    findOccurrances(&max_val, hexmap, &colorlist);

    cout << colorlist << " " << max_val << endl; // to do something

    mapStudent.erase(colorlist);
}
```

Comment: If I tried your way I would only get the same values all the time as findOccurrances only send back the most used value.

Comment: I dont think so, because i have erased it after i found it.